# Changing manifest values in RPM built with FPM

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging, fpm

I'm using the delightfully–named Effing Package Manager (FPM) to build RPMs and DEBs for a project.

After publishing the generated RPM with `createrepo`, I noted the following lines in the generated repo `UUID-primary.xml.gz`:

```
<location href="package-built-with-fpm.rpm"/>
  <format>
    [..]
    <rpm:vendor>me@machine-that-built-this</rpm:vendor>
    <rpm:buildhost>machine-that-built-this</rpm:buildhost>
    [..]
```

Short of changing my hostname and user, is there a way to define these with FPM?

I've got plenty of experience building and running DEB repos, this is my first attempt at RPMs.

Answer (score 1):

Typically RPM sets vendor through a build system configuration macro. The buildhost cannot be reset and was originally included in package metadata to help identify misconfigured build systems that caused "buggy" packages.

So in RPM vendor can be overridden but buildhost cannot (but you can configure a chroot with /etc/hosts to map the IP address arbitrarily).

Neither vendor/buildhost is used for much except information display, and so can be changed to anything you wish. I don't use fpm and don't know whether its possible to override using fpm.

Comment: Thanks for clarification regarding its use. The toolchain I'm using requires fpm, so hoping it's possible to override.